# SOQL - Count of records where the parent hasn't had child records in 1 year

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am trying to create a SOQL query (and later a report) in Salesforce that generates the following data:

Count of Child records grouped by Parent records where the Parent does not have child records created in the past year.

I tried this first; however, salesforce returned an error stating 'Nesting of semi join sub-selects is not supported'.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Training_Course__c
FROM Training_Record__c
WHERE Training_Course__c IN (
  SELECT Id
  FROM Training_Course__c
  WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT Training_Course__c
    FROM Training_Record__c
    WHERE CreatedDate != Last_n_Days:365
  )
)
```

The requirements are to use a single query to obtain the data requested without forcing them to run two reports and use Excel to get the data. I'm not sure if that's possible given Salesforce's constraints.

Is this possible in SOQL? If so, what can I do differently?

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect but a decent start, you'd need to manually call count/size/length on the child records (exact method depends on your client application's language). In a SF report you can group by parent Id and call it a day. Read about "cross filters" in SF reports.

```soql
SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities)
FROM Account
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate = LAST_N_DAYS:365)
LIMIT 100
```

This will not compile:

```soql
SELECT AccountId, COUNT(Id)
FROM Opportunity
WHERE AccountId NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate = LAST_N_DAYS:365)

Error: The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type
```

but if you really need something like that you could experiment, do it in 2 steps. Create helper field on account, tick the checkbox for eligible accs (with some nightly batch job maybe), then query based on that.

(normally you could do it with rollup summary field from opps to account but rollups have to be based on solid data, "deterministic". "LAST 365 DAYS", "TODAY" etc can't be used as rollup criteria)